# How to prevent UIAlertView from word wrapping

Tags: iphone

i have an Alert view, i have put a text in the message property,

```
message:@" my Text is .... ?";
```

when the alert view is shown, i have my text shown in one line and the "?" shown in other line, how can i show all my message Text in one line ?? thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you tried removing the spaces (ie. the one before the ?)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your text is probably too long to fit on one line.

You could force word wrap by removing the space between your text and the question mark?

```
message:@" my Text is ....?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , as i tested it and message was shown in single line

```
UIAlertView *alerrt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" message:@" my Text is .... ?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alerrt show];
[alerrt release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the behavior of UIAlertView, I suggest to sub-class UIWindow and implement one custom alertView by self.